# How can I specify virtual environment for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use Remote SSH Development for Python. How can I select a virtual environment? 
[image: I can only see standard Python in my list]

I can only see standard Python in my list
But how can I use the virtual environment that I have on remote machine `~/dev/bin/activate` ?

Comment: Have you enabled the extension in VSCode and connected to the SSH host you want to work with ?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to SSH host, but I can see only default python from the host. The screenshot shows python versions from host

Answer (score 1):

You should edit `settings.json` and point interpreter with parameter:

`"python.pythonPath": "~/dev/bin/python",`